# Material UI Tab - React - change active tab onclick

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have tab component in react project.

I have 2 tabs. Tab 1 and Tab 2. when user click on Tab 1's contain to select I want to change active tab from Tab 1 to Tab 2.

For ex.

I have two tabs Tab1 and Tab2. Tab1 has contain test1 and test 2. Tab2 has contain test3 and test4.

when user click on test1 (Tab1 's contain) I want to change active tab from  Tab1 to Tab2.

How can I do it.

Comment: One way is to maintain active tab in state and change the state every time tab is clicked and render content according to active tab value

Comment: @DevangNaghera How can I get Active Tab ?

Comment: Using ``this.state.activeTabe``

Comment: @DevangNaghera can you place your anser so I can understand. how to check which tab is active ? If I get active tab than may be i can handle this problem

Comment: Please refer to this link https://codepen.io/trey/post/tabbed-navigation-react
Hope it will help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've taken the [Basic Tabs](https://material-ui-next.com/demos/tabs/#basic-tabs) example from the material-ui doc and adapted it to do what you describe in your example.

Notice that in the original Basic Tabs example, the code tracks which tab is active using by setting a `value` property in `this.state`. In order to switch tabs when an item inside Tab One is clicked, all you need to do is update the `value` property when something is clicked inside Tab One. I indicated with a comment where that happens below.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';
import Tabs, { Tab } from 'material-ui/Tabs';
import Typography from 'material-ui/Typography';

function TabContainer(props) {
  return (
    <Typography {...props} component="div" style={{ padding: 8 * 3 }}>
      {props.children}
    </Typography>
  );
}

TabContainer.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
};

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    marginTop: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
  },
});

class BasicTabs extends React.Component {
  state = {
    activeTabIndex: 0,
  };

  handleChange = (event, value) => {
    this.setState({ activeTabIndex: value });
  };

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    const { activeTabIndex } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <AppBar position="static">
          <Tabs value={activeTabIndex} onChange={this.handleChange}>
            <Tab label="Tab One" />
            <Tab label="Tab Two" />
          </Tabs>
        </AppBar>
        {
          activeTabIndex === 0 &&
          // When the user clicks on Test One or Test Two, update the state
          // to display Tab 2
          <div onClick={() => this.setState({ activeTabIndex: 1 })}>
            <TabContainer >
              Test One
            </TabContainer>
            <TabContainer>
              Test Two
            </TabContainer>
          </div>
        }
        {
          activeTabIndex === 1 &&
          <div>
            <TabContainer>
              Test Three
            </TabContainer>
            <TabContainer>
              Test Four
            </TabContainer>
          </div>
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

BasicTabs.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(BasicTabs);
```

Comment: Thanks..spent few hours trying to figure this out

Answer (score 3):

Here is the simplest answer using hooks.

```
import { useState } from 'react';
..
const [tabState, setTabState] = useState(1);
...
  const handleTabs = (value) => {
    setTabState(value);
    return;
   }

let tabs_array = [<>{variable_with_contents_tab_1}</>, <>{tab_2_contents}</>];
```

Then in the render, you can provide the tab ui

```
<Paper className={classes.root}>
      <Tabs
        value={tabState}
        onChange={(event, value) => { handleTabs(value) }} 
        indicatorColor="primary"
        textColor="primary"
        centered
      >
        <Tab value={1} label='Tab1'>
        </Tab>
        <Tab value={2} label="Tab2" />
      </Tabs>
    </Paper>
    <Paper>
        {tabs_array[tabState-1]}
    </Paper>
```

Answer (score 0):

Faced with problem: onChange in Tabs hasn't worked, cause I forgot add {...other} when destructuring props and affected material-ui's needed props. Spent two hours to fix it =/

```
const Tab = ({myPersonalProps, ...other}) => {.... return <MaterialTab {...other}>}
```